# Validate so that same username is not in the other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
 class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_password
   validates_presence_of :username
   validates_uniqueness_of :username
 end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates_presence_of :username
    validates_uniqueness_of :username
 end
```

How you can see both models have a username! My question now is how i can vaidate my models so that username is unique in admin and user! Or better said that no username is in admin model and user model! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own validation like this:

```
def check_for_unique_name
  if !User.find_by_name(username)==nil or !Admin.find_by_name(username)==nil
    errors.add(:username, "already in use!")
  end
end
```

And then validate by:

```
validate :check_for_unique_name
```

But your Datamodel is not the best idea. Think about a new Model "Userrole" for the model "User". This can be "Admin" or "User".

Comment: or `if User.find_by_name(username) || Admin.find_by_name(username)`

Answer (score 3):

I think it would better to use [STI](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) (Single table inheritance) and move validations in parent model